# Android lint shows UnusedIds after converting findViewById to kotlin synthetic

Tags: android, kotlin, lint, kotlin-extension

I converted findViewById to kotlin synthetic after I did that I get the below error. But everything works the same. I have the exact issue before in fragment. In there I solve it by accessing the id after the onCreateView() i.e onViewCreated(). here I don't know how to resolve the issue? Thank you.

```
 The resource R.id.item_help_description appears to be unused [UnusedIds]
```

Here is my code

```
internal class HelpAdapter(titleDescriptionMap: Map<String, String>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<HelpAdapter.Item>() {
private var titles: Array<String> = titleDescriptionMap.keys.toTypedArray()
private var descriptions: Array<String> = titleDescriptionMap.values.toTypedArray()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
   parent: ViewGroup,
   viewType: Int
): Item = Item(
LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
  .inflate(R.layout.item_help, parent, false)
)

override fun onBindViewHolder(
holder: Item,
position: Int
) {
holder.itemView.item_help_description.text = descriptions[position]
holder.itemView.item_help_title.text = titles[position]
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = titles.size

 internal inner class Item(itemView: View) :
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
init {
  itemView.item_help_title.setOnClickListener { toggleDescriptionVisibility() }
  itemView.item_help_toggle_expand.setOnClickListener { toggleDescriptionVisibility() }
}

@SuppressWarnings("MagicNumber")
fun toggleDescriptionVisibility() {
  if (itemView.item_help_description.visibility == View.GONE) {
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(itemView.item_help_toggle_expand, "rotation", 0f, 180f).start()
    itemView.item_help_description.expand()
  } else {
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(itemView.item_help_toggle_expand, "rotation", 180f, 360f).start()
    itemView.item_help_description.collapse()
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: That appears to be a warning, not an error. Does it prevent you from compiling? By the way, I would recommend view binding over synthetic view references.

Comment: Yes,it prevents from compelling.